# How to submit object graph in a WebAPI action using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a WebAPI v2 action method to persist updates to an object graph using Entity Framework 6 and I'm a little unsure I've got the right syntax. *Project* is my root type which contains a collection of *Question*'s. The *Project* will already exist but the Post action may need to submit changes to the *Project* properties, changes to existing *Question*'s and add new *Question*'s.

The code I have is shown and commented below but the update requires a lot of work when I'd like to think there's a helper method that can do some of this for me:

```
[System.Web.Http.Route("{id:int}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(int id, [FromBody]Project project)
{
    // Validate the submitted project
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);

    // Fetch the existing project. This is here to perform row-level
    // security check. The user will have logged on and this confirms the 
    // organisation they work for. Behind the scenes I will compound the
    // query below to include a check for organisation id. This prevents
    // users submitted any project id and overwriting data that isn't theirs.
    // Would it make the pattern below better if this only executed a .Count()?
    // Would that mean the context would then be tracking the project before 
    // the update?
    var existingProject = _context.Projects.Include("Questions").FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectId == id);
    if (existingProject == null)
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ModelState);

    // Copy model updates to the project
    var projectEntry = _context.Entry(existingProject);
    projectEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(project);

    // Now work out which questions are updates or additions
    foreach (var question in project.Questions)
    {
        // No id so must be an addition
        if (question.QuestionId == 0)
        {
            existingProject.Questions.Add(question);
        }
        else
        {
            // Fetch the existing question so we can copy values
            var existingQuestion = existingProject.Questions.FirstOrDefault(q => q.QuestionId == question.QuestionId);
            if (existingQuestion == null)
            {
                // In a single user system finding ourselves here should not
                // be possible. Ideally we'll need to do some concurrency
                // when other users make updates or have some record locking
                // mechanism.
                existingProject.Questions.Add(question);
            }
            else
            {
                var questionEntry = _context.Entry(existingQuestion);
                questionEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(question);
            }
        }
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, project);
}
```

**Update** : I've also realised after submitting this that I'm not even dealing with deleting *Question*'s yet which, looking at my solution above, will not currently be catered for so I would appreciate that being considered too.

Comment: I am currently facing the same issue.  Did you ever find an answer to a sensible approach to deletions?

Comment: I did try [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) at one point but decided to continue with code similar to the above given EF will someday (fingers crossed) support this out-of-the-box and my use case is fairly self-contained for the moment.

Comment: I solved my problem by creating a custom generic Trackable Entity solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681390/json-net-serialise-custom-collection-with-additional-properties-and-on-add-to-ho

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for [Trackable-Entities](https://github.com/TrackableEntities/trackable-entities), here its wiki headline:

Trackable Entities supports *tracking changes* to entities in an object graph, so that they can be sent to a web service and persisted in a *single round trip* and within a *single transaction*.  This functionality is provided as a set of [NuGet packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=trackableentities).

The server-side NuGet packages provide an `ApplyChanges` extension method to Entity Framework's `DbContext` class, which traverses one or more object graphs, informing Entity Framework of each entity's change state.  After calling `SaveChanges`, you can then call `AcceptChanges` to set the state of all entities to `Unchanged` before returning them to the client.  There is also a `LoadRelatedEntities` method which you can call to populate reference properties on added entities.

The client-side packages provide a *change-tracker* for marking entities as `Added`, `Modified` or `Deleted` whenever they are inserted, modified or removed at any level in an object graph.  To start tracking changes, simply add one or more entities to a `ChangeTrackingCollection` and set the `Tracking` property to `true`.  When you want to persist changes, you can call `GetChanges` on the change tracker to get only changed items, so that unchanged entities need not be sent to the server, saving bandwidth and increasing performance.  Trackable Entities will correlate entities so that you can merge updated entities back into the original object graph by calling `MergeChanges`.  While you can certainly set `TrackingState` on entities manually, the change tracker is deployed as a *portable class library*, so you can use it from any .NET client, including desktop or mobile applications.

Another project to consider is [Breeze#](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.sharp).